# Wordpress: adding category filter to custom built wp list table

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom wp list table which displays posts according to my custom WP_Query,
I need to implement a category filter like the one shown below.

[image]

I need to display all categories as a drop-down and on selecting a particular category, I want to somehow apply this category filter to my wp_query,
Here is my WP_Query.

```
$wp = new WP_Query(
    array("post_type" => "post", 
          "post_status" => $status, 
          "meta_key" => "sc_imported", 
          "meta_value" => true, 
          "posts_per_page" => $per_page, 
          "paged" => $current_page, 
          "orderby" => $_REQUEST['orderby'], 
          "order" => $_REQUEST['order'] 
         ));
```

1. How to implement drop-down,
2. how to apply this category filter to the WP_Query.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function wp_dropdown_categories( $args );. It will create dropdown for categories.

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?> 
<?php $args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'show_option_none'   => '',
'orderby'            => 'ID', 
'order'              => 'ASC',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1, 
'child_of'           => 0,
'exclude'            => '',
'echo'               => 1,
'selected'           => 0,
'hierarchical'       => 0, 
'name'               => 'cat',
'id'                 => '',
'class'              => 'postform',
'depth'              => 0,
'tab_index'          => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'hide_if_empty'      => false
    'walker'             => ''
); ?>
```

Please [read here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) for complete function details.